# MvvmCross MvxColor cannot be converted to UI Color

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin IOS application with a lavel and I want to bind the color of the text to a property of the type MvxColor:

```
    public MvxColor ColorStateRequestLoginCode
    {
        get => colorStateRequestLoginCode;
        set
        {
            if (colorStateRequestLoginCode == value) return;

            colorStateRequestLoginCode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

        bindingSet.Bind(labelStatusRequestCode)
                  .For(lbl => lbl.TextColor)
                  .To(vm => vm.ColorStateRequestLoginCode)
                  .WithConversion("NativeColor");
```

I have added the color plugin and added it to the plugins loader:

```
    protected override void AddPluginsLoaders(MvxLoaderPluginRegistry registry)
    {
        base.AddPluginsLoaders(registry);
        registry.FindLoader(typeof(MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.iOS.Plugin));
    }
```

But when the view is called I get this in the output:

```
MvxBind:Error: 64.27 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TextColor for ColorStateRequestLoginCode - problem ArgumentException: Object of type 'MvvmCross.Platform.UI.MvxColor' cannot be converted to type 'UIKit.UIColor'.
      at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue (System.Object value, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) [0x00056] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:195 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) [0x00069] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:345 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:293 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x0000d] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Bindings\Target\MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.cs:48 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00093] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Bindings\Target\MvxConvertingTargetBinding.cs:65 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding+<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<UpdateTargetFromSource>b__0 () [0x00025] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Bindings\MvxFullBinding.cs:185
```

Do I have to do something else?

Comment: What if you write `.WithConversion(new MvxNativeColorValueConverter())`? Also, didn't the NuGet install the bootstrap in your iOS project?

Comment: No, in unfortunately none plugin installer the bootstrap file.. the same with your connectivity and settings plugin btw. For some I copied the one from android. But since it didn't work as expected I tried new things ^^ I will try your code and let you know!

Comment: I tried the code you proposed. the message isn't shown anymore. but the color text color stays black.

Comment: @Cheesebaron it seems the issue with the not created bootstrap files is an issue of project.json on ios. not sure if the same issue is with packageRef. but with packages.config it is created.